# Passing in-memory bitmap to Powerpoint using wxAutomationObject?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ole

I want to insert pictures in a PowerPoint slide. I've saved bitmap to the disk and called Add_Picture to insert picture, it is working properly.

What I want is without saving bitmap to the disk, add a picture in a PowerPoint slide.

Currently, i'm passing the picture to the clipboard and called the method Paste to do that.

Is there any better alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the OLE Automation?

Keep in mind though that this solution will not be portable - Windows only.